# Right Align an element INSIDE FLEXBOX DIV?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

If we have this structure of HTML

```
<div id="main">
  <div id="sub-1"><div>
  <div id="sub-3"><div>
  <div id="sub-3"><div>
</div>
```

And the SASS styles for that structure as:

```
#main
  display: flex
  flex-direction: column
  justify-content: center
  align-items: center
  align-content: center
  width: 1200px

#sub-1, #sub-2, #sub-3
  width: 100px
  height: 100px
```

With that structure we will have a column of 3 squares perfectly center-aligned. 
 But what if we want to move #sub-1 to the left and #sub-3 to the right? Is there a way to do that?

Thank you very much!

Comment: id's should be unique! use a class instead here.

Comment: @sburke0708 I'm guessing that it's a typo here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the property [`align-self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-self) like this:

```css
#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
#sub-1, #sub-2, #sub-3 {
  background:red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px
}
#sub-1 {
  align-self:flex-start;
}
#sub-3 {
  align-self:flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="sub-1"></div>
  <div id="sub-2"></div>
  <div id="sub-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: OMG! Thank you very much! I've been waiting for this for so long! Have a good day sir! Really really appreciate this!

Comment: np mate glad to help you @LanMai ... next time you use flexbox check this guide https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @LanMai here is another link you might like too: http://flexboxfroggy.com/